# Win 7: Black screen on boot up, before login screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, black-screen-of-death

**Problem:**

I find some interesting posting in this forum. Thanks for keeping this forum to help tech/user community. I like to pick up the brain of this forum to resolve the black screen issue. I am not sure, whether it caused by virus. I use Microsoft Security Essentials. I am not able to run this in command prompt.

I started my laptop this morning & login screen showed up. Once I entered my login credentials, I heard the sound that usually plays once a login is successful, but I ended up with a black screen. After this occurred, I had to hold down the power button to manually shut down the computer. Once I started it up again, I was prompted to do a system repair, which eventually ended up with all successful outcomes, but I now have a black screen with a cursor before the login screen now. I have no idea what caused this to happen. My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Model Z580 (500 GB HD, 6GB RAM).

**Tried Steps:**

I am not able to get into safe mode or any other mode, which all leads to a black screen described above.

I am able to use the **"Repair Your computer"** tools after pressing F8 during booting only . All other options leads to Black screen with cursor in the middle

**Last Known Good Configuration leads to same**

**Enable Low Resolution Video (640x480) leads to same**

**My Z580 is not responding to CTRL+ALT+DEL Windows Logo keys as well.**

**I tried SAFE Mode. It loaded couple of drivers and paused at CLASSPNP.SYS load. It went to Black screen with cursor at center.**

I am able to invoke control pannel from Command prompt of working PC by typing control.

**Z580 PC is not responding to control from command prompt (under Repair Your computer)  either.**

**Z580 is able to use the "Repair Your computer" tools after pressing F8 during booting .**

Under local user login it provided Start Repair option. As I pick this option, I got the following.

```
Problem signature
 Startup repair offline
 1 - 6.1.7600.16385
 2 - 
6.1.7600.16385
 3 - unknown
 4 - 21200332
 5 - autofailover
 6 - 
4
 7 - NoRootCause
 os v - 6.1.7600.2.1.0.2561
 locale id – 1033
```

Windows Memory Diagnostics is not launching and shows a black screen without cursor.

I am able to get into command prompt. I tried the following there.

I am not able to run cmd as admin

I reviewed the following past posting of forums on this subject & tried

[System File Checker: Run sfc /scannow & analyze its logs in Windows 7 / 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-system-file-checker-analyze-its-logs-in-windows-7-vista)

[Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service][2]

[How to analyze the log file entries that the Microsoft Windows Resource Checker (SFC.exe) program ge...][3]

SFC /SCANNOW showed up

"Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service

I did "net start trustedinstaller"

"Windows Resource Protection detected pending repair restart the computer"

I ran repair options using sfc /scannow /offbootdir=x:\ /offwindir=D:\windows

and got "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them "

I did findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log >sfcdetails.txt

I will be glad to attach the zip file that contain CBS.LOG & [SR] tag extract (xxx.txt).
I did not any find ERRORS there, SFC ended with message saying "found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them" . It is misleading. There is no [SR] tag pointing to corrupt files.

**Does SFC through false positive like this?**

**I ran chkdsk /r  . Results**

```
File verification completed.
0 bad file records processed.
0 EA records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)...
Index verification completed.
0 unindexed files scanned.
0 unindexed files recovered.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.
0 KB in bad sectors.

 Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50.
```

**I ran the window Defender Offline using CD boot. It did not find any offensive items in Quick Scan or FULL Scan.**

It is puzzling me.

Did anyone of this forum face such issues?

Thanks for helping

**Updated on 8/7**
**============**

Here are my HDD config:

Volume ### Ltr Label Fs Type Status Info

---

Volume 0 F WDO_Media64 UDF DVD- Healthy
Volume 1 C NTFS Partition Healthy
Volume 2 D Windows7_OS NTFS Partition Healthy
Volume 3 E LENOVO NTFS Partition Healthy
Volume 4 G FAT Removable Healthy
Volume 5 LENOVO_PART NTFS Partition Healthy Hidden

I ran CHKDSK /F /X for C, D, E. All resluted to "Windows has checked the file system and found no problems."

**F8 ===> Repair Computer===> Command Prompt ===> Works OK**
F8 ===> Repair Computer===> Start up Repair ==> Results into "Startup repair could not detect a problem"

F8 ===> Repair Computer===> System Restore ===> "No restore points has been created on yout computer system drive"
F8 ===> Repair Computer===> System Image Recovery ===> "Windows cannot find a system impage on this computer"
F8 ===> Repair Computer===> windows Memory Diagnostiyics ===> "Black screen with Cursor in the middle"

**After getting into Command prompt**

I run net user

User accounts for \

---

Administrator Guest
The command completed with one or more errors

**It did not list other users in my laptop. I do not know why?**

I need to pick the brain of this forum for these issues.

Thanks for looking into .

Comment: Try booting off a Windows 7 install cd and repairing

Comment: I do not have win 7 Install cd. How does this different from "Repair Your computer" tools after pressing F8 during booting only ? This is the only option responding. It is not finding restore point under this option. I am able use only Command prompt.

Comment: Is this issue caused by hardware/win 7/Virus/Malware/BIOS ? Need your insight.